# Jquery cookie plugin - conditional content determined by cookie being set

Tags: jquery, forms, cookies, conditional-statements

I have a sign up form that is displayed to all new site visitors.  If a user fills out the form, the next time they visit the site, I would like to display a "welcome back" message where the form would usually sit.

I am trying to do this via the jquery cookie plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).

My form would look like this:

```
<div id="sign_up_form_wrapper"><form id="sign_up" action="" method="POST" name="form">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1">&nbsp; I accept the terms and conditions</a>
<br /><br /><input type="submit" value="ENTER">
</form></div>
```

And I am setting my cookie here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$().ready(function()
{
    $('#sign_upm').submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#sign_up input[name=checkbox]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $.cookie('agreed_to_terms', '1', { path: '/', expires: 999999 });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

That will set the cookie when a user has checked the box, but now I need to do somehting like this:

if the cookie has been set, do this:

```
<div id="sign_up_form_wrapper">
<p>Welcome back, John</p>
</div>
```

otherwise do this:

```
<div id="sign_up_form_wrapper">
<!-- full form code here -->
</div>
```

Any ideas or pointers would be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boris Guéry is close:

HTML:

```
<div id="sign_up_form_wrapper">
<!-- full form code here -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    if ($.cookie('agreed_to_terms') == 1) {
        $('sign_up_form_wrapper').html('<p>Welcome back, John</p>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the cookie and check if it is set.

```
var $signupFormWrapper = $('<div />');

if ( 1 == $.cookie(agreed_to_terms) )
{ 
     var $message = $('<p />').html('Welcome back, John');
} else {
     var $message = $('<p />').html('<form>Your full form</form>');
}

$signupFormWrapper.append($message);
```

Do this where you want depending on the event which has to be triggered

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will do the trick.

However, should this block be wrapped in javascript tags? When I do this, it displays the full HTML as text rather than executing the conditonal.

Apologies but my js is very limited.

Thanks

Comment: You have to do it in js, I updated the code to create the message and wrap it in the div, then append it where you want in the body for example.

Comment: Many thanks, but Jeffery To's solution seemed to work out better

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add it just over

```
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you.

I am taking these responses to mean I would do this:

<script type="text/javascript">

if ( 1 == $.cookie(rspca_signed_up) )
{ 
    <div id="sign_up_form_wrapper">
      <p>Welcome back, John</p>
    </div>
} else {
 <div id="sign_up_form_wrapper">
      <!-- full form code here -->
    </div> 
}
</script>

But when I do this, I again can't get the conditional to work, just get the HTML output as text.